# How to do a ~= vector operation in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector

I'm trying to write my own program to sort vectors in matlab. I know you can use the sort(A) on a vector, but I'm trying to code this on my own. My goal is to also sort it in the fewest amount of swaps which is kept track of by the ctr variable. I find and sort the min and max elements first, and then have a loop that looks at the ii minimum vector value and swaps it accordingly.

This is where I start to run into problems, I'm trying to remove all the ii minimum values from my starting vector but I'm not sure how to use the ~= on a vector. Is there a way do this this with a loop? Thanks!

```
clc;
a = [8 9 13 3 2 8 74 3 1] %random vector, will be function a once I get this to work
[one, len] = size(a);
[mx, posmx] = max(a);
ctr = 0; %counter set to zero to start
%setting min and max at first and last elements
if a(1,len) ~= mx
    b = mx;
    c = a(1,len);
    a(1,len) = b;
    a(1,posmx) = c;
    ctr = ctr + 1;
end
[mn, posmn] = min(a);
if a(1,1) ~= mn
    b = mn;
    c = a(1,1);
    a(1,1) = b;
    a(1,posmn) = c;
    ctr = ctr + 1;
end

ii = 2; %starting at 2 since first element already sorted
mini = [mn];
posmini = [];
while a(1,ii) < mx
[mini(ii), posmini(ii - 1)] = min(a(a~=mini))
if a(1,ii) ~= mini(ii)
   b = mini(ii)
   c = a(1,ii)
   a(1,ii) = b
   a(1,ii) = c
   ctr = ctr + 1;
end
ii = ii + 1;
end
```

Comment: How important is the *fewest amount of swaps* part? ([Cycle sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort)) Which one of the bazillion [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) are you trying to implement?

Comment: Also: You can simplify the swapping process in Matlab. To swap the second and third value of a vector just use: `a([3,2]) = a([2,3])`.

Comment: It looks a lot like [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) by the way! (Which will not really fulfill your *fewest amount of swaps*...)

Comment: I thought my process of swapping was intensive, thanks for the tip! I mean, my first attempt of sorting was going from left to right comparing the two and putting the greater one after the lesser one, but that required multiple passes to get everything sorted. This way I believe takes less swaps because there aren't redundant swaps.

Comment: I have looked at all the different sorting algorithims but couldn't find one that takes the fewest swaps. So I'm kind making my own up as I go. I might implement something like while a(ii) < a(ii + 1) to swap chunks of presorted elements to not have to do individual swaps... But is there a method that truly does the fewest swaps possible? I couldn't find an algorithm that seemed to do that.

Comment: I linked the *cycle sort* above, which is optimal in terms of the total number of writes. Not all sorting algorithms are based on swapping, so that's that. By the way: Minimum number of writes/swaps doesn't necessarily mean fastest algorithm.

Comment: As for the problem, the `~=` operator works per element for full vector, try `~isequal(a,b)`.